# Position of figures and text are not proper

Tags: positioning

Question:

Actually i am working with an example in which figures dragged above the question text i cant understand, what is the problem. Any help..

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=0.6in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.7in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\headsep=10pt
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Example~1}

    This is the body text of my example 1...........
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{6cm}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzDefPoint(-5,0){B}
            \tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}
            \tkzDefPoint(-1,5){A}
            \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
            \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=00pt](B)
            \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](C)
            \tkzLabelPoints[above](A)

            \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](-3,-2){A1}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](2,-2){A2}
            \tkzDrawVector[thick,<->](A1,A2)

            \tkzDefPoint(-2.5,3.1){D}
            \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=2mm](D)

            \tkzDefPoint(-0.65,3.1){E}
            \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=2mm](E)
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption*{(i)}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hspace{1cm}
        \begin{subfigure}{6cm}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzDefPoint(2,2){B}
            \tkzDefPoint(8,0){C}
            \tkzDefPoint(7,5){A}
            \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
            \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=00pt](B)
            \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](C)
            \tkzLabelPoints[above](A)

            \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](-3,-0.8){A1}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](2,-2.5){A2}
            \tkzDrawVector[thick,<->](A1,A2)

            \tkzDefPoint(5.1,3.85){D}
            \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0mm](D)

            \tkzDefPoint(7.3,3.3){E}
            \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=0mm](E)

            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption*{(ii)}
        \end{subfigure}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [floating option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/156344) to your `figure` environment

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=0.6in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.7in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\headsep=10pt
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Example~1}

    This is the body text of my example 1...........
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{6cm}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzDefPoint(-5,0){B}
            \tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}
            \tkzDefPoint(-1,5){A}
            \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
            \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=00pt](B)
            \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](C)
            \tkzLabelPoints[above](A)

            \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](-3,-2){A1}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](2,-2){A2}
            \tkzDrawVector[thick,<->](A1,A2)

            \tkzDefPoint(-2.5,3.1){D}
            \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=2mm](D)

            \tkzDefPoint(-0.65,3.1){E}
            \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=2mm](E)
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption*{(i)}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hspace{1cm}
        \begin{subfigure}{6cm}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzDefPoint(2,2){B}
            \tkzDefPoint(8,0){C}
            \tkzDefPoint(7,5){A}
            \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
            \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=00pt](B)
            \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](C)
            \tkzLabelPoints[above](A)

            \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](-3,-0.8){A1}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](2,-2.5){A2}
            \tkzDrawVector[thick,<->](A1,A2)

            \tkzDefPoint(5.1,3.85){D}
            \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0mm](D)

            \tkzDefPoint(7.3,3.3){E}
            \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=0mm](E)

            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption*{(ii)}
        \end{subfigure}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: will it work for every similar problem?

Comment: @Sandy Yes. Read more in the linked question

Comment: @Sandy, it will not work in every cases. use only `h` option doesn't enable to flow figure to  available space. better is to use `htb`, which enable, that float is moved to top of the next page (if at point of insertion is not enough space for it) or to bottom of the same page. otherwise  it can happen that float be pushed to the end of document.